# holding values in text field even after closing application

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have a save button. After clicking the save button my values of text field must be saved, i.e, next time when i run my application the saved values of the text field should remain there.

Comment: Sounds good. What is your question? Is there anything not working yet? Is there any code involved which you could share?

Comment: actually this is a small part of he project. All I need to do is is my application there will be a save button and few text fields. i will write some values to the text fields. now i will press the save button. so next time when i will  open the application the text fields will show the values i last entered as i pressed the save button before closing the application. now i need code to retain the  values of the text field. can you help please

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not to the comments. Additionally, explain what you've tried and where you are stuck

Comment: basically i need to prevent my form from clearing its data ,  the next time i open it.its possible in java script. but is it possible in java netbeans? if yes then how?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all such information

Comment: well, there are multiple ways to handle this.
1) use a database
2) write the saved information to a file which you will parse on application startup
3) save the information to cookies

Without more information there is not much we can do to help you. Also stackoverflow is not here, to do your work. it is here to help you if you get stuck or have questions